# wxPython - Can't make wx.StaticText align inside a wx.StaticBoxSizer

Tags: alignment, wxpython

how it going?

I'm trying to align two wx.StaticText inside a horizontal box, which is inside a vertical wx.StaticBoxSizer. See for yourself. I guess the code says what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self)
        left = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'left', style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        right = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'right', style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

        hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBox.Add(left)
        hBox.Add(right)

        sizer.Add(hBox)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since the removal of `wx.ALIGN_LEFT` and `wx.ALIGN_RIGHT` in horizontal boxsizers and the introduction of:
`wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "!(flags & wxALIGN_RIGHT)" failed at /tmp/pip-install-8ko13ycp/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/sizer.cpp(2168) in DoInsert(): Horizontal alignment flags are ignored in horizontal sizers`,

it's an issue.

Another option is to use the `spacing` in the sizer instruction to the Left and/or Right. e.g.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self, "Test")
        left = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'left')
        right = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'right')

        hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBox.Add(left, 0, wx.RIGHT, 100)
        hBox.Add(right, 0, wx.LEFT, 100)

        sizer.Add(hBox)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I I'll very gladly adapt your code to my solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to specify a `size` to make the aligment work!

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self)
        left = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'left', size=(175, 15), style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        right = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'right', size=(25, 15))

        hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBox.Add(left)
        hBox.Add(right)

        sizer.Add(hBox)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```